# Access data from table view cell in Swift

Tags: xcode, uitableview, swift

I'm having trouble accessing an optional string in swift from a table view cell. Each cell has a title label as well as a detail text label and the amount of cells at any given time in the table view is dependent on the user (the table view is used to display saved values). Since the strings saved as the detail text label's text in each cell are way too long to read in the table view, I wish to load them in another view that is segued to when a cell is pressed. This is my prepare for segue method:

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {


        if segue.identifier == "cellSegue"
        {

          let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()!)

          var transfer : ExplanationView = segue.destinationViewController as ExplanationView

          if let unwrapped = cell?.textLabel?.text!
          {

            transfer.infoText.text = unwrapped

          }


        }

   }
```

When a segue is performed, I get a fatal crash, the offending line is "transfer.infoText.text = unwrapped" and Xcode tells me it found nil when unwrapping an optional. During my debuggingg efforts, I've tried "println(cell?.textLabel?.text!)" and Xcode prints "Optional(String)" where "String" is the actual string I'm trying to access so it seems like I'm on the right track, but obviously there's something I'm missing. I've also tried "cell?.textLabel?.text" but I get the same error. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is not `unwrapped` but instead `transfer.infoText.text`.  Your `IBOutlets` are not set up at the time of the `prepareForSegue`.  You need add a property (`var`) to your destination view controller to hold the `unwrapped` value.  Then in `viewDidLoad` when the `IBOutlet`s are set up, copy the string to your text field.

Answer (score 5):

You shouldn't ever extract data from a view. You should extract data from a model. The fact that you have a tableView with cells implies you have a model for the data that goes in those cells. It might be an array of strings or whatever. Instead of trying to extract the data from the cells, just get the data from the data model you used to populate the cells. Something like:

```
let selectedIndexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow()
let selectedData = data[selectedIndexPath.row]
```